# Valores mínimos y máximos de los días de la semana

Tags: c#, lista, linq

Necesito obtener los gastos máximos y mínimos de los días de la semana de un archivo de texto.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora:

**CLASE GASTOS:**

```
public class Gastos
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public int Gasto { get; set; }
}
```

**PROGRAMA:**

```
string path = @"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\gastos.txt";

List<Gastos> DGastos = (from p in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
                        let parts = p.Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        where parts.Length == 2
                        select new Gastos
                        {
                            Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[0].ToString()),
                            Gasto = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1].ToString()),
                        }).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Dias\tMin\tMax");

var agrupar = DGastos.GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.DayOfWeek);

foreach (var dia in agrupar)
{
    var minimo = dia.Min(x => x.Gasto);
    var maximo = dia.Max(x => x.Gasto);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

**ARCHIVO DE TEXTO**

```
FECHA   GASTOS
01/05   1241
01/05   0
02/05   12912
02/05   121
03/05   91
03/05   10
04/05   12
04/05   1212
05/05   854
05/05   81
06/05   1241
06/05   723
07/05   12912
07/05   194
08/05   91
08/05   102
09/05   243
09/05   12
10/05   76
10/05   124
11/05   54
11/05   553
12/05   124
12/05   325
13/05   865
13/05   144
14/05   654
14/05   89
15/05   850
15/05   6
```

Mi problema radica en que la utilización de Min y Max con Día me devuelve el Día de menor consumo pero es inválido ya que, por ejemplo:

**RESULTADO OBTENIDO:**
LUNES MIN: 0 MAX: 1241

**RESULTADO ESPERADO:**
LUNES MIN: 193 MAX: 1241

El resultado de `193` se obtiene mediante la suma del gasto del día Lunes del día `08/05`. No sé cómo obtener ese resultado mediante operaciones de LINQ ya que me compara cada resultado individual y lo que yo necesito es comparar por gastos del DÍA (es decir total de gastos del DIA `1/05` `8/05` `15/05`)

```
GASTO LUNES 1/05: 1241
GASTO LUNES 8/05: 193
GASTO LUNES 15/05: 865
```

Y comparar los tres y obtener el máximo y mínimo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te falta una etapa intermediaria.  Antes de agrupar por día de semana, necesitas agrupar por día del mes para poder obtener la suma de gastos por día.

```
List<Gastos> DGastos = (from p in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
                        let parts = p.Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        where parts.Length == 2
                        select new Gastos
                        {
                            Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[0].ToString()),
                            Gasto = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1].ToString()),
                        })

                        // Te falta este agrupamiento adicional...
                        .GroupBy(t => t.Fecha)
                        .Select(g => new Gastos
                        {
                            Fecha = g.Key,
                            Gasto = g.Sum(t => t.Gasto)
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

Con este agrupamiento intermediario adicional, ahora obtienes una lista de gastos por día del mes. Ahora sí puedes usar el código que ya tienes para obtener el mínimo y máximo por día de la semana:

```
var agrupar = DGastos.GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.DayOfWeek);
foreach (var dia in agrupar)
{
    var minimo = dia.Min(x => x.Gasto);
    var maximo = dia.Max(x => x.Gasto);
}
```

Comment: Te agrego una coma que falta Luego del Key, que sino no compila la solución. Lo demás está perfecto. Hay alguna otra manera de resolucion ?

Comment: Ya lo correg, gracias. En cuanto a tu pregunta, siempre hay más de una manera de resolver un problema, todas con sus ventajas y desventajas.